# How to interpret a iOS crash log and see the reason it crashed

Tags: ios, xcode, dsym

Can anyone tell me what line to look at to see why my app crashed ? This is my first time experiencing a crash log and im kind of lost as in what direction to go in.  Also if anyone is familiar with these could you tell me what are possible reasons this crash occured ?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x198217758 __exceptionPreprocess + 232
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19741fd00 objc_exception_throw + 59
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1981306ac -[NSObject+ 222892 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 143
3   UIKitCore                       0x1c5124aa8 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 287
4   CoreFoundation                  0x19821d0fc ___forwarding___ + 1411
5   CoreFoundation                  0x19821eeb0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 95
6   Foundation                      0x198cb72f4 __NSFireTimer + 87
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1981a7fb8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 31
8   CoreFoundation                  0x1981a7ce4 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 899
9   CoreFoundation                  0x1981a74c8 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 251
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1981a2198 __CFRunLoopRun + 1811
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1981a1764 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 451
12  GraphicsServices                0x19a3dddd4 GSEventRunModal + 107
13  UIKitCore                       0x1c50f800c UIApplicationMain + 215
14  Game                            0x1041a116c 0x104120000 + 528748
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x197c60ffc start + 3


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197dac0bc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000197d05250 __abort + 156
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000197d051b4 __abort + 0
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000197407ff0 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001974081b4 default_unexpected_handler+ 8628 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000197420144 _objc_terminate+ 24900 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001974149d4 std::__terminate(void (*)+ 59860 ()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001974145cc __cxa_rethrow + 148
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019741fee0 objc_exception_rethrow + 48
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001981a17d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
10  GraphicsServices                0x000000019a3dddd4 GSEventRunModal + 108
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c50f800c UIApplicationMain + 216
12  Game                            0x00000001041a116c 0x104120000 + 528748
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000197c60ffc start + 4
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log and the full exception message would help - I can see from the stack trace that a function (selector) has been called on an object that does not have that function - Which object and which function will be in the exception message.

Comment: when you say the function "will be in the exception message" how do I get the exception message ? This crash happened when my phone was not connected to Xcode